# Creating dictionary from a list of special characters

Tags: python, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I'm working on this small script: basically it's mapping the list elements (with special characters in it) to its index to create a dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: latin-1 -*-

ln1 = '?0>9<8~7|65"4:3}2{1+_)'
ln2 = "(*&^%$£@!/`'\][=-#¢"

refStr = ln2+ln1

keyDict = {}
for i in range(0,len(refStr)):
    keyDict[refStr[i]] = i


print "-" * 32
print "Originl: ",refStr
print "KeyDict: ", keyDict

# added just to test a few special characters
tsChr = ['£','%','\\','¢']

for k in tsChr:
    if k in keyDict:
        print k, "\t", keyDict[k]
    else: print k, "\t", "not in the dic."
```

It returns the result like this:

```
Originl:  (*&^%$£@!/`'\][=-#¢?0>9<8~7|65"4:3}2{1+_)
KeyDict:  {'!': 9, '\xa3': 7, '\xa2': 20, '%': 4, '$': 5, "'": 12, '&': 2, ')': 42, '(': 0, '+': 40, '*': 1, '-': 17, '/': 10, '1': 39, '0': 22, '3': 35, '2': 37, '5': 31, '4': 33, '7': 28, '6': 30, '9': 24, '8': 26, ':': 34, '=': 16, '<': 25, '?': 21, '>': 23, '@': 8, '\xc2': 19, '#': 18, '"': 32, '[': 15, ']': 14, '\\': 13, '_': 41, '^': 3, '`': 11, '{': 38, '}': 36, '|': 29, '~': 27}
```

which is all good, except for the characters `£`, `%` and `\` are converting to `\xa3`, `\xa2` and `\\` respectively. Does any one know why printing `ln1`/`ln2` is just fine but the dictionary is not. How can I fix this? Any help greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

---

**Update 1**

I've added extra special characters - `#` and `¢` and then this is what I get following @Duncan's suggestion:

```
! 9
? 7
? 20
% 4
$ 5
....
....
8 26
: 34
= 16
< 25
? 21
> 23
@ 8
? 19
....
....
```

Notice that 7th, 19th and 20th elements, which is not printing correctly at all. 21st element is the actual `?` character. Cheers!!

---

**Update 2**

Just added this loop to my original post to actually test my purpose:

```
tsChr = ['£','%','\\','¢']
for k in tsChr:
    if k in keyDict:
        print k, "\t", keyDict[k]
    else: print k, "\t", "not in the dic."
```

and this what I get as result:

```
£   not in the dic.
%   4
\   13
¢   not in the dic.
```

Whist running the script, it thinks that `£` and `¢` are not actually in the dictionary - and that's my problem. Anyone knows how to fix that or what/where am I doing wrong?

eventually, I'll be checking for the character(s) from a file (or a line of text) in the dictionary to see if it exists and there is a chance of having character like `é` or `£` and so on in the text. Cheers!!

Comment: There is nothing wrong at all!

Comment: A note about style, you could do `for i, x in enumerate(refStr): keyDict[x] = i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my humble opinion it would be useful to learn about unicode in general and [it's use in python](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)

if you are **not** interested to know why people had to mess up things so you have to deal with a '\xa3' instead of having just a plain `£` then Duncan answer above is perfect and tells you everything you want to know.

## Update (regardin your Update #2)

please assert your file is saved with latin-1 encoding and **non utf-8** as it's now and your test will pass (or just change `#-*- coding: latin-1 -*-` to `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`)

This is a thing you could easily understand reading (and understanding) contents from my link above:

your file is saved as utf-8 this means for char `£` **2 bytes are used** but since you tell python interpreter encoding is latin-1 he will use **each of the 2 utf-8 bytes** of `£` for a key.

Infact I can count 19 chars in `ln2` but if you issue `len(ln2)` it will return 21.

When you test for `'£' in keyDict.keys()` you are looking for a 2-char string while each of the 2-chars got its own key in dictionary, that's why it won't find it.

Also you can test `len(keyDict)` and find it's longer than what you expect.

I guess this explains everything, please understand not all the story is easy to be explained in a single webpage but the link above, in my humble opinion is a nice starting point, mixing some story and some coding examples.

Cheers

P.S.: I'm using this code, saving it as UTF-8 and it works flawlessly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

ln1 = u'?0>9<8~7|65"4:3}2{1+_)'
ln2 = u"(*&^%$£@!/`'\][=-#¢"

refStr = u"%s%s" % (ln2, ln1)

keyDict = {}
for idx, chr_ in enumerate(refStr):
    print chr_,
    keyDict[chr_] = idx

print u"-" * 32
print u"Originl: ", refStr
print u"KeyDict: ", keyDict

tsChr = [u'£', u'%', u'\\', u'¢']
for k in tsChr:
    if k in keyDict.keys():
        print k, "\t", keyDict[k]
    else: print k, repr(k), "\t", "not in the dic."
```

Comment: @Roman: first it's not a _problem_, second where / how should the OP learn **why** `£` is represented as `\xa3`?

Comment: just to clarify: on my shell (utf-8) `£` is `\xc2\xa3` and `'£'.decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1')` is `\xa3`. I think we are talking about char encoding and learning about unicode is a good starting point IMHO.

Comment: @Roman: I did look in the page you mentioned, which didn't actually help to answer my question. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: if you just want to know about what a spark plug do (sparkles) and not about why it's there then you are right, I thought you wanted to know **why** `£` needs to be represented as `\xa3` and also that it changes based on the encoding you choose. If not, I made a wrong guess, I'm afraid...

Comment: @neurino: I don't think really understood the point you wanna make here (apologizes for my ignorance) but if you have a look in the original post (I've updated with new lines now), hopefully you'll understand what my original problem is. If you can offer any solution, it'll be appreciated. cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: The preferred way to deal with strings of text in Python is using unicode strings. You are using strings of bytes, not strings of unicode characters. That's not a problem in latin-1, but in other encodings '£' is two bytes, and the code simply won't work, and it won't be easily combined with external code. Using unicode for everything fixes this. Also, are you sure that the encoding is latin-1, because from the output it would seem to be utf-8?

Comment: @Rosh: My final goal is to create a dictionary like that and then check for the character(s) from a file (or a line of text) in the dictionary to see if it exists. And there is chance of having character like `é` or `£` and so on in the text. There  should be a way of handling this - isn't it? Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: briefly the trick is setting `#-*- coding: xxxx -*-` to the real encoding used saving the python source file.

Comment: @neurino: I know it's not easy to explain in a single page, but you effort is well appreciated. I've to agree, I never realized that `ln2` actually counts 21; thanks for pointing that out. Now, as for my original problem, I already swapped the original encoding line with `#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in the script and saved it (I'm using `vi` on OS X, Ubuntu and SL5) but `£` etc. still being reported as not present. Did I understand it correctly? I must have been doing something wrong then. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: well I can't tell you what encoding your `vim` uses, it's your duty, I can tell you that, if in distro, using my geany editor, I swap encodings to match (change doc encoding to match `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` or change this one to match doc encoding) or not I solve / experience your same problems. Also did you converted strings to unicode? `'£'` to `u'£'`

Comment: @neurino: The 'vim' on OS X is definitely using UTF-8 but that hardly matters, I believe and that doesn't make any "practical" sense to me at all. When you writing a toolkit (and specially running on a grid) it's almost impossible to make sure all your users are gonna run the script in identical environment. And if that's the case, in this particular case, then python (or any other language in question) must have a work around that issue.

Comment: @neurino: I did change it to this: `tsChr = [u'£','%','\\',u'¢']` if that's what you mean.

Comment: @neurino: Success, at last!! Thanks for the sample code. One more issue: is there any way to automatically detect those few extra special characters and put a `u` in front of them. cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers: `u''` just means its a `unicode` object carrying all necessary informations needed for encoding / decoding. **always use `u` also with ascii chars** like `0`, `a`, etc (see `ln1` in my code for example). Common practice is `decode` while reading from files, work on unicode strings, and decode before writing results to files. See my link at [Reading and writing unicode data](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)

Comment: @neurino: thanks a lot for helping me understand the underlaying problem. Now it's working just fine every possible way I expected. cheers!!

Answer (score 6):

When you print a dictionary or list that contains strings Python will display the `repr()` of the strings. If you `print repr(ln2)` you'll see that nothing has changed: your dictionary key is just the latin-1 encoding of '£' &c. characters.

If you do:

```
for k in keyDict:
    print k, keyDict[k]
```

then the characters will display as you expect.

Comment: I've updated my original post. Whist, it almost worked, still doesn't work for few of them. cheers!!

Comment: at this point I guess the perfect answer for this question is _it works this way, carry on and live with it_...

Comment: @neurino: So, you mean to say python can't handle all of those special characters? I's hard to believe, even with my limited python knowledge. Sorry!

Comment: @MacUsers: please update in my answer, I think it will clarify everything (I hope)